# Can i stack stereo recordings on stereo and then output stereo mix?

Tags: production

I record stereo mix with drums and synth. Drums are mono (only hihat left) and synth has a bit of width. Then i layer on top stereo pad and another synth. Is it right to render that? Or should i render stereo Drums, Synth, Pad as a whole piece?

Comment: I would go back and do some jiggery-pokery on the drums before going any further. I used to have a utility that could stereo-ize a mono recording in various ways. Can't remember its name, but there are probably quite a few nowadays. Even if the drums and synth are already mixed together the same utility should be able to tell the one from the other and separate them to some extent. I often do submixes as I go along, then mix the submixes. I keep the unmixed tracks just in case I need them, and I often do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are mixing for certain special playback circumstances like a quadrophonic system, your final mix should be a single stereo mix of all the elements of your track.